# QuerySet inheritance in django-polymorphic

Tags: django

I'd like to add `filter_by_user` methods to all QuerySet classes defined for child polymorphic models and use them to filter objects of every model when called for the base model. `filter_by_user` methods may be different for different child models. Is this possible?

I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
class MyBaseQuerySet(PolymorphicQuerySet):
    def filter_by_user(self, user):
        return self.all()


class MyBaseModel(PolymorphicModel):
    ...
    objects = PolymorphicManager(MyBaseQuerySet)


class MyChild1QuerySet(MyBaseQuerySet):
    def filter_by_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(fieldA__lt=user.profile.propA)


class MyChild1Model(MyBaseModel):
    fieldA = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    objects = PolymorphicManager(MyChild1QuerySet)


class MyChild2QuerySet(MyBaseQuerySet):
    def filter_by_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(fieldB__gt=user.profile.propB)


class MyChild2Model(MyBaseModel):
    fieldB = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    objects = PolymorphicManager(MyChild2QuerySet)
```

When I call `MyBaseModel.objects.filter_by_user(john)` magic doesn't happen and only base queryset filter_by_user is called.

Comment: does `PolymorphicManager` instantiate the `QuerySet` passed to it or what exactly is it's purpose?

Comment: @LawrenceBenson I guess it makes polymorphic filtering working. I took it from the documentation: https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#using-a-custom-queryset-class

Comment: i'm not quite sure I understand what you are expecting... `MyBaseModel` referes to `MyBaseQuerySet`. When you call `MyBaseModel.objects.filter_by_user(john)` you will get `return self.all()`. You don't specify how to handle the name input

Comment: @LawrenceBenson I specify how to handle it in MyChild1QuerySet & MyChild2QuerySet and expect that corresponding methods will be called.

Comment: but how do you expect Django to know which of those to call? i would expect this to work as any normal polymorphism. if you call `MyChild2QuerySet` you should get `return self.filter(fieldB__gt=user.profile.propB)`. you will always get the function of the class you are calling it from or higher up if not implemented by that class

Comment: @LawrenceBenson sure Django itself can't do that, but I though it shouldn't be hard to achieve such behavior using django-polymorphic.

Comment: and how you you acheive that? if it's a filter, it will go through all objects at one. how could it suddenly use a diffrent filter for the same query?

Comment: @LawrenceBenson there will be many queries executed. try django-polymorphic, it does cool tricks